html2canvas genera miniatura
tengo el problema que al renderizar el pdf se genera en el margen superior izquierdo una miniatura de la misma renderizacion, ademas tambien si ingreso desde el celular no renderiza la pagina completa cortando el final de la pagina... les dejo el codigo con el que genero el pdf y una imagen del resultado. Desde ya muchas gracias


const DATA: any = document.getElementById('leerPDF');
      const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'a4');

      const option = {
        background: 'white',
        scale: 3
      };

      html2canvas(DATA, option).then((canvas: any) => {

      var img1 = canvas.toDataURL(this.imagenUno);
      var img2 = canvas.toDataURL(this.imagenDos+'/jpeg');
      var img3 = canvas.toDataURL(this.imagenTres+'/jpeg');
      var img4 = canvas.toDataURL(this.imagenCuatro+'/jpeg');
      var img5 = canvas.toDataURL(this.imagenCinco+'/jpeg');
      var imgAgente = canvas.toDataURL(this.foto);

    //   // Add image Canvas to PDF
      const bufferX = 15;
      const bufferY = 15;
      const imgProps1 = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img1);
      const imgProps2 = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img2);
      const imgProps3 = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img3);
      const imgProps4 = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img4);
      const imgProps5 = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img5);
      const imgPropAgente = (doc as any).getImageProperties(imgAgente);

      const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * bufferX;

      const pdfHeight1 = (imgProps1.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps1.width;
      const pdfHeight2 = (imgProps2.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps2.width;
      const pdfHeight3 = (imgProps3.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps3.width;
      const pdfHeight4 = (imgProps4.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps4.width;
      const pdfHeight5 = (imgProps5.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps5.width;

      doc.addImage(img1, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight1, undefined, 'FAST');
      doc.addImage(img2, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight2, undefined, 'FAST');
      doc.addImage(img3, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight3, undefined, 'FAST');
      doc.addImage(img4, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight4, undefined, 'FAST');
      doc.addImage(img5, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight5, undefined, 'FAST');
      doc.addImage(imgAgente, 'JPEG', bufferX, bufferY, 35, 35, undefined, 'FAST');
      return doc;
    }).then((docResult: any) => {

      docResult.save(`propiedad:${this.domicilio}.pdf`);
    });





Tu pregunta debe contar con un [MCVE]. En tu pregunta, donde hay un botón "ejecutar" yo al presionarlo debería ver exactamente el mismo error que describes (me parece que te falta agregar, al menos, algo de HTML). Y por último, favor agregar las etiquetas de HTML y javascript a tu pregunta



<div class="container" id="contenedorTabla">
    <div class="col-12">

        <!-- //////// TITULO /////////// -->
        <div class="titulo">
            <h1>LISTADO DE PROPIEDADES</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- ///////// TABLA ///////// -->
        <div class="listado">
            <table class="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="tituloTabla">
                        <td class="itemTitulo">Mostrar</td>
                        <td class="itemTitulo">Foto</td>
                        <td class="itemTitulo">Domicilio</td>
                        <td class="itemTitulo">Propietario</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="datosTabla">
                    <tr *ngFor="let propiedad of propiedades | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 7, currentPage: page }">
                        <td class="item">
                            <input [(ngModel)]="propiedad.mostrar" value="propiedad.mostrar" type="checkbox" id="inputMostrar" (change)="mostrarUocultar(propiedad._id, propiedad.mostrar)">
                        </td>
                        <td class="itemImg"><img src="https://marinoinmobiliaria.com.ar/{{ propiedad.imagen1 }}" id="imagen"
                                class="card-img-top"></td>
                        <td class="item">{{ propiedad.domicilio }}</td>
                        <td class="item">{{ propiedad.idPropietario.nombre }}</td>
                        <!-- <td class="itemBtn"><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modificarPropiedad(propiedad._id)">Modificar</button></td> -->
                        <td class="itemBtn">
                            <a class="btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard/modificar-prop', propiedad._id]"
                                (click)="modificarPropiedad(propiedad._id)">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-edit btnModificar"></i>
                                <p>modificar</p>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="itemBtn">
                            <a class="btn" (click)="eliminarPropiedad(propiedad._id)">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt btnEliminar"></i>
                                <p>eliminar</p>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="itemBtn">

                            <a class="btn btnExportar" (click)="exportarPropiedad(propiedad._id)">
                                ver ficha
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
            <!-- PAGINACION -->
            <div class="paginacion">
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event" previousLabel="Anterior" nextLabel="Siguiente"></pagination-controls>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
